# How to fix 'target of URI does not exist' in general?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, angular-dart

I'm currently working on a Angular Dart project. It seems that packages in general can't be found. I've tried several combinations of pub commands (get, upgrade, repair cache), but none of them worked.

I'm not looking for the solution of a specific package, but for tips how to approach this problem in general. So: **What are crucial steps to take / places to look at?**

I should mention: I'm currently working with IntelliJ IDEA, the Dart plugin and sdk are setup correctly, but the dart section of my project went completely red, after I **moved** the whole dart directory.

Comment: Usually restarting the IDE fixes that. Haven't seen this happen often.

Comment: It sounds like the move might have changed some references. Have you tried running the pub commands from a terminal or command prompt? It could be something messed up with IntelliJ.

By "moved the whole dart directory", are you referring to moving the location of the dart SDK or the your AngularDart project?

Comment: I was referring to my project. It seems that it has something to do with IntelliJ. Opened the project in some other IDEs and it's working fine. Will analyse it further and maybe post an issue to JetBrains later.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular v5, then this is probably referring to a generated file, such as `foo.template.dart`. In that case, you will need to do an initial build via `webdev build` or `webdev serve` so that those files can be generated.

Once you've done the build, the analyzer should detect them. You may need to restart the analyzer in intellij if it doesn't update automatically.